# How deploy JAVA Spring Framework to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

i hope u can help me to fix this.

I'm tried to create a project using JAVA Web Spring DAO, that project running well (using mvn clean package tomcat:run), but when i tried to upload file.war to Tomcat my project got an error. All variabel in jsp file cannot be execute as syntax. For more detail i attach a pic.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are using differen Tomcat versions between the plugin and the deployment target?

Comment: Picture is not shown at my end, could you please post the console errors

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the jars for the JSP Expression Language are not present when you deploy your application to tomcat standalone. Could you please verify that `jasper-el.jar` and `el-api.jar` are in tomcat's lib folder ?